# how to make list to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

```
["BANYULE : 'Abbotsford', 'Airport West', 'Albert Park', 'Alphington'",
 "BRIMBANK : 'Altona', 'Altona North', 'Armadale', 'Ascot Vale'"]
```

I have one string list, and I want to change it to pandas dataframe:

```
**BANYULE**      **BRIMBANK**
Abbotsford    Altona
Airport West  Altona North
Albert Park   Armadale
Alphington    Ascot Vale
```

this formate
what should I do?

```
test = pd.DataFrame(local_list).T
```

I have try this one, but it can not have header.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer:

change your list to dictionary

```
local_list = {"BANYULE" : ['Abbotsford', 'Airport West', 'Albert Park', 'Alphington'], 
              "BRIMBANK" : ['Altona', 'Altona North', 'Armadale', 'Ascot Vale']}

#only use .T if you want transpose your index and columns.
test = pd.DataFrame(local_list).T
```

### Further illustration:

If you rechecked your list you will notice that it only has two elements both of type string

```
l = ["BANYULE : 'Abbotsford', 'Airport West', 'Albert Park', 'Alphington'", 
              "BRIMBANK : 'Altona', 'Altona North', 'Armadale', 'Ascot Vale'"]

print(l[0]) #output: BANYULE : 'Abbotsford', 'Airport West', 'Albert Park', 'Alphington'

print(l[1]) #output: BRIMBANK : 'Altona', 'Altona North', 'Armadale', 'Ascot Vale'
```

You should pass these data as *ndarray (structured or homogeneous), Iterable, dict, or DataFrame* as pandas library stated in their [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) documentation.

So you should modify your data to be for example:

```
local_list = {"BANYULE" : ['Abbotsford', 'Airport West', 'Albert Park', 'Alphington'], 
              "BRIMBANK" : ['Altona', 'Altona North', 'Armadale', 'Ascot Vale']}

test = pd.DataFrame(local_list).T
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
# From List to Dataframe
import pandas as pd

# list of strings

lst = [["BANYULE : 'Abbotsford', 'Airport West', 'Albert Park', 'Alphington'"], 
       ["BRIMBANK : 'Altona', 'Altona North', 'Armadale', 'Ascot Vale'"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
print(df)
```

Result:

[image]